# What's the use of ImageCollection.errorMatrix() in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, confusion-matrix

In the docs there are two versions of the errorMatrix function:

`ee.FeatureCollection.errorMatrix`

and

`ee.ImageCollection.errorMatrix`

I've been sampling points from my classified images to create error matrices using the former, which is working just fine, but I'm curious about when/how the ImageCollection version is used.

I assumed `ImageCollection.errorMatrix` would implicitly convert pixels to points, then check if my classification band matched a reference band. It's not clear if the Image Collection should be a collection of images with two bands or two images with one band each (reference and classification), or something else. Any combination I try just gives me a 1*1 EM with a value of 0.

The two arrangements that I thought might work:

```
var classifiedImage = ee.Image(someClassifiedImage)
//Some classified image with two bands: "reference" and "classification"

///Create image collection. Using one image now, but could probably do multiple
var classifiedImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([classifiedImage]);

var imageEM = classifiedImageCollection.errorMatrix("reference", "classification")
```

Or

```
var referenceImage= ee.Image(someReferenceImage)

var classifiedImage = ee.Image(someClassifiedImage)

var classifiedImageCollection= ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([referenceImage, classifiedImage]);

var imageEM = classifiedImageCollection.errorMatrix("tailings", "classification")
```

Both of these produce an error matrix of `[[0]]`

To make it a little more confusing, the args for `ImageCollection.errorMatrix` are identical to those of `ee.FeatureCollection.errorMatrix`, including:

`this:collection (FeatureCollection): The input collection`

Again, I can just sample the image and get an EM from that, but I'm curious if there's a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

In Earth Engine, images are a special kind of feature, and image collections are a special kind of feature collection. So, `ImageCollection.errorMatrix` is just another name for `FeatureCollection.errorMatrix`, and does exactly the same thing — working with *properties* of the images (features) in the collection.

Many things exist because it would be more irregular for them *not* to exist. They could be better documented, of course.